# A better name for "Content" in Global Navigation

Tags: navigation, terminology, classification

I'm working on a client's website and I want to categorize Articles, Videos, and Past Newsletters under a classification in the global navigation to save space. I'm between the words "content" and "media" but neither seem powerful or description.

The site is for a company that puts on conferences, the videos are mostly interviews of thought leaders and executives, the articles are about workplace leadership and related things written by thought leaders.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: What is the specific domain? Is it news? Try to be more specific so we can generate more choices.

Comment: I update the question with more context, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I think @maxathousand has an answer that should cover your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any context, several terms come to mind.

If the content is updated regularly, or based on recent events:

- Stream
- Feed
- News

If the content is consumed for leisure:

- My Stories

If the content is shared by other users:

- Posts
- Updates

Any of these terms—and certainly many others—could probably work. Each varies slightly in the type of conceptual model and tone they communicate to the user. Which is appropriate is based on your site's model.

---

Based on your update, I might go with the term *Resources*. This communicates that the content will be informative and accurate.

Comment: Thank you, Max. Sorry for the lack of context, I updated my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Every company's in-house marketing group has it in their head that there's demand for their archived newsletter content. Having worked on the supply side of that marketing tactic, I have yet to see anything substantiate that.

Articles and videos are a different story. Over time, well-written original content is the gift that keeps on giving. The best stuff really gives wisdom away, and for that there is endless demand.

So from an information architecture perspective I think it's problematic to find the perfect single-word label to encapsulate both things the audience is looking for (wisdom, answers, inspiration) and things you want push on them via newsletter.

Focusing on that "teaching" content, I'd survey the competitive landscape of websites for inspiration and see where they put their version of the same thing, and maybe come up with some candidate labels and tree-test them with a tool like [TreeJack](https://www.optimalworkshop.com/treejack).

Example task & results (hypothetical:)

*"Where would you find videos about workplace leadership?"*

Path A: Media -> Videos - 63% success rate 
Path B: Content -> Videos - 48% success rate

So if you ran at least representative 100 people through such a tree test you can be comfortable those results are within a realistic ballpark.

And remember - it's marketing, not rocket science. Try something and learn as you go. Don't overdo it on statistical inference unless you have time to kill or are trying to publish a scientific paper in a journal.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the content was from thought leaders on workplace management and leadership, so you could try approaching this a user's perspective i.e. what would interest a visitor to the site and motivate them to click on the link? I'm guessing based on the context that the user is someone interested in reading about business/workplace leadership - something along the lines of "Learn from Thought Leaders".

It's relatively long but more engaging that a purely descriptive label. "Resources" has always been an overly generic and convenient label.